# gitignore ignore all except config.xml file inside second-level directory?

Tags: git, gitignore

I googled but hard to find the proper solution.
If I have below files, how can I ignore all files except these three files?

1. package-01/config.xml
2. package-02/config.xml
3. package-03/config.xml

```
./
|-- .git/
|-- .gitignore
|-- README.md
|-- config.xml
|-- configuration
|-- package-01/
|   |-- settings/
|   |   |-- id
|   |   `-- links
|   |-- config.xml
|   `-- other_files
|-- package-02/
|   |-- settings/
|   |   |-- id
|   |   `-- links
|   |-- config.xml
|   `-- other_files
|-- package-03/
|   |-- settings/
|   |   |-- id
|   |   `-- links
|   |-- external_packages/
|   |   |-- 1/
|   |   |   |-- settings.xml
|   |   |   |-- config.xml
|   |   |   `-- id
|   |   |-- 2/
|   |   |   |-- settings.xml
|   |   |   |-- config.xml
|   |   |   `-- id
|   |-- config.xml
|   `-- other_files
```

I tried this but failed.

```
*
!.gitignore
!README.md
!/**/*.xml
!**/*.xml
!**.xml
!/*/*.xml
!*/*.xml
```

Comment: The first line `*` is the cause. It ignores the first level directories. As a result all  under the directories are ignored and cannot be excluded, which is explained at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format, `It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. `. But I don't know how to write the correct patterns to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the directories containing `config.xml` from being ignored, then ignore all their contents but exclude each `config.xml`.

```
/*
!.gitignore
!README.md
!/package-01
/package-01/**
!/package-01/config.xml
!/package-02
/package-02/**
!/package-02/config.xml
!/package-03
/package-03/**
!/package-03/config.xml
```

The problem with your approach was indeed, as ElpieKay mentioned in a comment:

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.

(see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)